# Horizontal lines visible on retina monitor

Tags: display

I have a retina monitor, but I can see horizonal "pixel" lines on my screen. This occurred soon after I installed Yosemite, then the problem disappeared, now it has reappeared again. Restarting the computer or restarting in safe mode does nothing. How can I fix this issue?

My system details are as follows:

OS X Yosemite, Version 10.10.1
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1526 MB

Color LCD:
  Display Type: Retina LCD
  Resolution: 2880 x 1800 Retina
  Retina: Yes
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Built-In: Yes

Comment: If you open System Prefs > Displays > Display & switch to 'Scaled' what resolution does it say is active?

Comment: What kind of horizontal lines? Bands of color?